# Struts login Error submit onclicked environment:tomcat8 IDE:java9 Jquery UI draggable not scrolling the sortable container

Tags: authentication, struts

**i have a struts logindemo ,tomcat is started, but when i click the submit button , i do get a ERROR result**

### LoginAction.java

```
package com.actions;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.forms.UserForm;

public class LoginAction extends Action {
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UserForm userform = (UserForm) form;
    System.out.println("username:" + userform.getUsername());
    System.out.println("password:" + userform.getPassword());
    return null;
}
}
```

### UserForm.java

```
package com.forms;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class UserForm extends ActionForm {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

### login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/strutslogindemo/login.do" method="post">
        user：<input type="text" name="username"></br>
        pass：<input type="password" name="password"></br> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="userForm" type="com.forms.UserForm"></form-bean>
    </form-beans>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/login" name="userForm" type="com.actions.LoginAction">
            <forward name="ok" path="/WEB-INF/ok.jsp"></forward>
            <forward name="err" path="/WEB-INF/err.jsp"></forward>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### console err message

```
[INFO] ActionServlet - Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
[ERROR] Digester - Begin event threw exception <java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")>java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.internalGetMethod(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.getMethod(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:390)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.<init>(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtilsBean.java:925)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:933)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:830)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:433)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin(SetPropertiesRule.java:252)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1453)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1827)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initChain(ActionServlet.java:1687)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[ERROR] ActionServlet - Exception loading resources <org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 24; Error at line 33 char 24: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 24; Error at line 33 char 24: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3181)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3207)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1456)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1827)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initChain(ActionServlet.java:1687)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.internalGetMethod(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.getMethod(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:390)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.<init>(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtilsBean.java:925)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:933)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:830)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:433)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin(SetPropertiesRule.java:252)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1453)
    ... 48 more

[ERROR] ActionServlet - Unable to initialize Struts ActionServlet due to an unexpected exception or error thrown, so marking the servlet as unavailable.  Most likely, this is due to an incorrect or missing library dependency. <javax.servlet.ServletException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 24; Error at line 33 char 24: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")>javax.servlet.ServletException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 24; Error at line 33 char 24: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initChain(ActionServlet.java:1691)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 24; Error at line 33 char 24: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3181)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3207)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1456)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1827)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initChain(ActionServlet.java:1687)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.internalGetMethod(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.getMethod(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:390)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor.<init>(MappedPropertyDescriptor.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtilsBean.java:925)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:933)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:830)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:433)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin(SetPropertiesRule.java:252)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1453)
    ... 48 more

2月 06, 2018 1:03:23 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Marking servlet action as unavailable
2月 06, 2018 1:03:23 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
严重: Allocate exception for servlet action
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 24; Error at line 33 char 24: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:402)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

### Login image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TN9C.png)

### ERROR image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWVhH.png)

### eclipse path image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcfqu.png)

Comment: Please show us your `org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml` in `C:\Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/strutslogindemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar`.

Comment: I have add the file chain-config.xml  ↑↑

Comment: You may be able to work around this issue by adding a definition for `accessDeclaredMembers` to `conf/catalina.policy`.

Comment: In file java.policy,[permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";] added ,it can work . thank you

Answer (score 0):

### chain-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
    $Id: chain-config.xml 481833 2006-12-03 17:32:52Z niallp $

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
   
         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
   
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->


<!--
    This file contains definitions of the standard Chain Of Responsibility
    chains that emulate Struts 1.2 processing functionality.  These chains
    are defined in a catalog named "struts" so that the application can
    use the default catalog for its own purposes, without any potential for
    name clashes.

    $Id: chain-config.xml 481833 2006-12-03 17:32:52Z niallp $
-->


<catalog name="struts">

    <define name="lookup"
            className="org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand"/>
    <!-- ========== Servlet Complete Request Chain ========================= -->

    <chain name="servlet-standard">

        <!-- Establish exception handling filter -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ExceptionCatcher"
                catalogName="struts"
                exceptionCommand="servlet-exception"/>

        <lookup
                catalogName="struts"
                name="process-action"
                optional="false"/>

        <lookup
                catalogName="struts"
                name="process-view"
                optional="false"/>

    </chain>


    <!-- ========== Action Processing chain ======================== -->
    <chain name="process-action">

        <!--
             This chain attempts to emulate (most of) the standard request
             processing in the standard org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor
             class, by performing the corresponding tasks in individual Commands
             that are composable.  The following list defines a cross reference
             between the processXxx methods and the Commands that perform the
             corresponding functionality:

             processMultipart        Integrated into servlet and legacy classes

             processPath             SelectAction (which also does processMapping)

             processException        ExceptionCatcher / ExceptionHandler

             processLocale           SelectLocale

             processContent          SetContentType

             processNoCache          RequestNoCache

             processPreprocess       LookupCommand with optional="true".  Multiple
                                     occurrences of this can easily be added, to
                                     support additional processing hooks at any
                                     point in the chain without modifying the
                                     standard definition.

             processCachedMessages   RemoveCachedMessages

             processMapping          SelectAction (which also does processPath)

             processRoles            AuthorizeAction

             processActionForm       CreateActionForm

             processPopulate         PopulateActionForm

             processValidate         ValidateActionForm / SelectInput

             processForward          SelectForward

             processInclude          SelectInclude / PerformInclude

             processActionCreate     CreateAction

             processActionPerform    ExecuteAction
        -->


        <!-- Look up optional preprocess command -->
        <lookup
                catalogName="struts"
                name="servlet-standard-preprocess"
                optional="true"/>


        <!-- Identify the Locale for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SelectLocale"/>


        <!-- Set (if needed) the URI of the original request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SetOriginalURI"/>


        <!-- Set (if needed) no cache HTTP response headers -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.RequestNoCache"/>


        <!-- Set (if needed) the HTTP response content type -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SetContentType"/>


        <!-- Remove messages cached in the Session -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.RemoveCachedMessages"/>


        <!-- Identify the ActionConfig for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SelectAction"/>


        <!-- Authorize the selected ActionConfig for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.AuthorizeAction"/>


        <!-- Create (if needed) the ActionForm for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.CreateActionForm"/>


        <!-- Populate the ActionForm for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PopulateActionForm"/>


        <!-- Validate the ActionForm for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ValidateActionForm"/>


        <!-- Select the appropriate ForwardConfig for return to input page -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SelectInput"/>


        <!-- Lookup and execute a chain command if the current ActionConfig is
             so-configured. -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ExecuteCommand"/>


        <!-- Select the appropriate ForwardConfig for action mappings that only
             have an ActionForward -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SelectForward"/>


        <!-- Select the include uri (if any) for the current action mapping -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.SelectInclude"/>


        <!-- Perform the include (if needed) -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformInclude"/>


        <!-- Create (if needed) the Action for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.CreateAction"/>


        <!-- Execute the Action for this request -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction"/>
    </chain>

    <!-- ========== View Processing chain ======================== -->
    <chain name="process-view">


        <!-- Lookup and execute a chain command if the current ForwardConfig is
             so-configured. -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ExecuteForwardCommand"/>

        <!-- Follow the returned ForwardConfig (if any) -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward"/>


    </chain>

    <!-- ========== Servlet Exception Handler Chain ======================== -->

    <chain name="servlet-exception">

        <!--
              This chain is designed to be invoked (by o.a.s.c.ExceptionCatcher)
              if an unhandled exception is thrown by any subsequent command
              in a processing chain (including the one that invokes a Struts
              action).  The standard definition of this chain supports the
              exception mapping of Struts 1.1, but can be replaced in order
              to handle exceptions differently.
        -->

        <!-- Execute the configured exception handler (if any) -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExceptionHandler"/>

        <!-- Follow the returned ForwardConfig (if any) -->
        <command
                className="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward"/>

    </chain>


</catalog>
```